# Why list קונם and קונס explicitly in Kol Nidrei but not other Kinuyim?

Tags: yom-kippur, language, nedarim-shevuot, tractate-nedarim, kol-nidre

[Nedarim 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.1.2) lists several kinnuyim, alternate expressions you can use for making a neder.

In the [Ashkenazi](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Yom_Kippur_Ashkenaz_Linear%2C_Kol_Nidrei.13) version of Kol Nidrei that I'm familiar with as well as the [Nusach Sefarad](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Yom_Kippur_Sefard%2C_Kol_Nidrei.3) one I found on Sefaria, we explicitly mention two of these, קונמי and קנוסי, as well as כנויי to catch the rest.

Once we say כנויי, why do we need קונמי and קנוסי at all?  And, given that we do say those, why *don't* we say קונחי and the rest of them?

Comment: I don't pretend to be an expert on versions of the machzor.  If there are other versions of Kol Nidrei that handle this differently please share them.

Comment: From the Talmud, seems קונם was way prominent when formulating a neder. But this does not answer קונסי etc

Comment: IIRC there is a version "וקונמי וקונחי וקונסי". Hence, recalling the 3 listed on Nedarim 1,1.

Answer (score 2):

In this 19th century Nusach Sefarad Machzor with Yidish instruction, the commentary at the bottom indicates that the word קנוסי is actually reffering to a קנס - Monetory fine, that one imposes upon oneself which he is not legally obligated to pay. Accordingly it is not referring to a *Kinnui* (Variation) of "קונם" which is a vow rendering an object forbidden, rather an exclusively monetory acceptance. Note that it would be spelt קונסי with the *Vav* before the *Nun* had it been the Kinui of קונמי.

[image]

Comment: I would have thought it would be _kenasei_ in that case, so the nekudos aren't that strong a proof.  But I don't know Aramaic grammer that well so maybe I'm wrong.